# Unable to set text in NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, desktop-application, nstextview

::Edit::
It works now? haha, maybe I just didn't save my latest IB...who the hell knows.
Thanks!

Hey,

This is my first time playing around with desktop applications (I have experience with iphone applications) and I'm stuck - My text view will not update to show any text:

```
.m:
@synthesize textView;

    NSString *txt = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"txt = %@", txt);
    [textView setString:txt];

.h:
    IBOutlet NSTextView *textView;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSTextView *textView;
```

And IB says textView -> Text View, so everything looks good:

- NSLog above outputs the contents of the url resource Im fetching

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double check if the outlets are done in IB. That's probably the reason (textView is probably `nil` here).

Comment: My Controllers textView is set to the Text View in the nib (like I said in my description) - what exactly are you saying?

Comment: I saw it in the description, but we often forget to do so. Put a break point and see if 'textView' is 'nil' there. Check if the nib is actually loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Where is this `setString` code being called? It's possible the IB outlet isn't instantiated yet. You can check this with a simple

```
if (textView) {
    NSLog(@"textView is not nil);
} else {
    NSLog(@"textView is nil");
}
```

To be sure that everything is set up when you call this, make sure it's after 'awakeFromNib' is called in any objects created through IB.

See [NSNibAwaking Protocal](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

Can you double check NSTextView properties like isEditable, textColor etc to make sure none of them are set incorrectly.

Other than that the code looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I reconnected everything in IB, saved, rebuilt and it worked...= [